# Why is canvas still rebuilding and rebatching its data?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I want to avoid the rebuild / rebatch process from occurring when showing/hiding UI elements so I followed the advice from [HERE](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/best-practices/other-ui-optimization-techniques-and-tips) : ***workaround is to place the UI to be shown/hidden onto its own Canvas ... and ... enable/disable the Canvas component on this object.***

Tested by placing 5000 images under a separate empty Canvas and only enabled/disabled the canvas component on that canvas parent gameobject using this script :

```
public class CanvasScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Canvas canvas;
    private Image[] images = new Image[5000];

    public void CreateImages()
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
       {
           GameObject NewObj = new GameObject(); //GameObject
           images[i] = NewObj.AddComponent<Image>(); //Image Script                       
           NewObj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().SetParent(canvas.transform); //set child
        }
    }

    public void EnableDisableSubCanvas()
    {
        canvas.enabled = !canvas.enabled;
    }
}
```

***Issue*** : Calling the EnableDisableSubCanvas() still generates big spikes (~100ms) on UGUI.Rendering.UpdateBatches calls. Why is this happening or what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What does the profiler say?

Comment: It shows UGUI.Reendering.UpdateBatches taking 50ms on canvas.enable=false and ~100ms on canvas.enable=true. This is indeed twice as fast as compared to enabling/disabling each image GameObject, but still I would expect it from not spiking at all.

Comment: Have you explored other options of suspending the rendering of the canvas, other than `enabled` property? I remotely remember my own attempts of avoiding those stupid spikes, and it may be the way.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I've played now with toggling the SetAlpha between 0 and 1 in the CanvasRenderer component assigned to each UI Object and it eliminated the spike. The end result was the same, 5000 images shown or hidden but the UpdateBatches took < 1ms instead of 100ms. So I'll consider this a viable workaround for showing/hiding UI obj in my project. Nonetheless, I'd still like to find out why the results contradict what unity says in that tutorial link.

Comment: I just filed a bug report linked to this post.  I'll update if they create a bug.